# Clean ZSH pwd prompt from Node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal, zsh

I've recently updated the Node.js installed in my machine with `nvm install --lts` and my ZSH terminal now shows:

> ~ via ⬢ v14.17.3

how can I clean this "prompt" pwd message?
It's constantly showing up instead of just '~'

Answer (score 3):

Some folks using `spaceship-prompt` [were running into a similar issues and it appears to have to do with](http://%20https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-prompt/issues/167#issuecomment-313875172)

- having a `package.json` file somewhere
- `node_modules` directory somewhere

Try locating and removing those as described in the posted `git issue`, additionally, there is guidance on how to disable or ignore via the `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, node version is showing everywhere, But the problem was only in package.json in the home directory

Comment: so what did you do to fix it?

Comment: Just remove it from home directory)
In my case, it's MacOS, and I have an empty package.json in the ~ directory. Remove it, restart the terminal (source command did not work for me) and node version will be shown only in the directories where it is used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).